# How to calculate the Principal Curvature of an ellipsoid with given equation?

Tags: calculus, curvature

Consider the ellipsoid S of equation $x^2 + \frac{y^2}{4} + \frac{z^2}{9} = 1$. For each of the six points of intersection with the coordinate axes compute: the principal curvatures and the principal directions. Use symmetry to reduce the number of computations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameterize the surface (for instance, by solving for one of the variables -- which one will depend on the point), compute the shape operator using the Weingarten equations (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_operator#Shape_operator), and diagonalize it. The eigenvalues are the principal curvatures and the eigenvectors the principal directions.

To parameterize the surface, solve for one of the variables. For example,

$$x = \sqrt{1 - y^2/4-z^2/9}$$ is valid for the part of the surface near $(1,0,0)$. Then
$$r(u,v) = \left(\sqrt{1 - u^2/4-v^2/9}, u, v\right)$$
describes the surface near $(1,0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you User7530.                                             But can you please explain(or guide me to a link)as to how can I compute the shape operator from the given equation?(x^2 + (y^2)/4 + (z^2)/9 = 1)

Comment: Do you know how to compute the first and second fundamental forms?

Comment: I think I have got the formula for finding the coefficients of the 1st and 2nd fundamental form,that is E,F,G and e,f,g. But I need your help in Parametrize the surface and finding u,v value.REST is clear to me.